# Как работает алгоритм конвертирования big.Int в строку?

Tags: golang, rsa

Объясните пожалуйста как данный алгоритм превращает число типа `big.Int` в читабельную строку, я уже изучил как он работает, но поясните пожалуйста моменты в комментариях к коду. Данный пример я взял с сайта [роззета код](http://www.rosettacode.org/)

```
func (r *RSA)decrypt(){
    const size = 32 // размер массива 
    var bb big.Int
    plain := new(big.Int).Exp(r.c,r.d,r.n) // decrypt message

    var db = make([]byte,size)
    dx := size
    buff := big.NewInt(0xff) // почему здесь берётся число 255 ? и ниже операция логического AND происходит именно с этим числом?

    for plain.BitLen() > 0{
        dx--
        db[dx] = byte(bb.And(plain,buff).Int64()) // 
        plain.Rsh(plain,8) // почему тут необходим сдвиг на 8 бит?
    }
    fmt.Println("Decoded number as text:", string(db[dx:]))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь обычный алгоритм разложения числа на байты. На псевдокоде выглядит так:

```
while (number > 0)
{
    nextByte = number % 256 // остаток от деления
    number = number / 256   // целочисленное деление
}
```

Для оптимизации скорости вместо остатка от деления на 256 можно использовать битовое `and 255`, а вместо деления на 256, можно использовать сдвиг вправо на 8 бит.